# connect to my website from multiple external remote sites

Tags: http, remote-access, high-availability

I remember seeing a website where I could type in my home page url, and then get a list of a bunch of servers that connected to my url in real time, from all over the world.

the report would show how long it took for that remote site to connect to my site, or whether it timed out.

I cannot recall the name of the site anymore. Does anyone know of the same or similar website for testing connections to my site from remote locations?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863908/programmatic-automated-way-to-determine-is-my-site-reachable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about Dotcom-monitor?

Website Speed Test - https://www.dotcom-tools.com/website-speed-test.aspx

Comment: That's not the specific site I remember, but that one is good nonetheless. Thanks, remind me to upvote once I get 15 rep on this site.

Comment: No worries.  Just glad to help.